# Can we use the legacy build system for react native ios in Xcode 10.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I was using xcode 9.4 for react native 0.55 in production. But apple keeps sending mail each time a build is submitted to appstore, forcing the xcode update for the latest ios 12 sdk.

I updated xcode and solved the bugs I was getting during a local build following [this blog post](https://zivost.com/blog/xcode-10-causes-haywire-for-react-native-developers/). The build is successful running from xcode locally.

However, the build is failing in circle-ci and the glog script that I run doesn't work for some reason.

So, I want to ditch the new build system and go back to the legacy build system.

Is it okay to release a build with legacy build system? I've heard that the new build system helps for faster builds with swift code. I don't have any swift code and want to push an update immediately to the appstore.

This update is a blocker.

Comment: Yes. It’s fine to use the legacy build system.

Comment: Will apple ever force to use the new build system in the future? @Andrew

Comment: Who can tell what Apple will decide in the future.